# my code for the button to export data in an xlsx file (Excel) does not work

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

This is my code but my code is not working on my button to export XLSX data from Odoo

```
# coding: utf-8
from odoo import fields, models, api, _
import time
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
from odoo.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT as DATE_FORMAT, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT as DATETIME_FORMAT
import xlsxwriter
from io import BytesIO

class AccountDailyBook(models.TransientModel):
    _name = "account.daily.book"

    date_start = fields.Date("Fecha desde", required=True, default=date.today().replace(day=1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    date_end = fields.Date("Fecha hasta", required=True, default=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', required=True, default=lambda self: self.env.company)

    def imprimir_pdf(self):
        for rec in self:
            format_new = "%d/%m/%Y"
            data = {
                'ids': 0,
                'form': {
                    'date_from': self.date_start,
                    'date_to': self.date_end,
                    'date_from_str': self.date_start.strftime(format_new),
                    'date_to_str': self.date_end.strftime(format_new),
                    'company': self.company_id.id
                }
            }
            return self.env.ref('l10n_ve_full.report_daily_book').report_action(self, data=data)  # , config=False
        
    def imprimir_xlsx(self):
        
        for rec in self:
            format_new = "%d/%m/%Y"
            data = {
                'ids': 0,
                'form': {
                    'date_from': self.date_start,
                    'date_to': self.date_end,
                    'date_from_str': self.date_start.strftime(format_new),
                    'date_to_str': self.date_end.strftime(format_new),
                    'company': self.company_id.id
                }
            }


            # Crear el archivo
            output = BytesIO()
            workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'in_memory': True})
            sheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Reporte')

        # Escribir los encabezados
            sheet.write(0, 0, 'Código')
            sheet.write(0, 1, 'Nombre')
            sheet.write(0, 2, 'Débito')
            sheet.write(0, 3, 'Crédito')

        # Escribir los datos
            row = 1
            for doc in data['docs']:
                sheet.write(row, 0, doc['code'])
                sheet.write(row, 1, doc['name'])
                sheet.write(row, 2, doc['debit'])
                sheet.write(row, 3, doc['credit'])
                row += 1

        # Escribir los totales
            sheet.write(row, 1, 'Total')
            sheet.write(row, 2, data['debit_total'])
            sheet.write(row, 3, data['credit_total'])

        # Cerrar el archivo
            workbook.close()
            output.seek(0)

            return self.env.ref('l10n_ve_full.report_daily_book').report_action(self, data=data)

        # Devolver el archivo como una respuesta HTTP
            return {
                'name': 'report_daily_book.xlsx',
                'type': 'binary',
                'data': output.read(),
                'context': self.env.context,
            }

class AccountInventoryBookReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.l10n_ve_full.report_daily_book_template'

    @api.model
    def _get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):

        date_start = datetime.strptime(data['form']['date_from'], DATE_FORMAT)
        date_end = datetime.strptime(data['form']['date_to'], DATE_FORMAT)
        company_id = self.env['res.company'].search([('id','=',data['form']['company'])])
        move_line_ids = self.env['account.move.line'].search([])
        datos = []
        debit_total = 0
        credit_total = 0
        self._cr.execute("select aa.code, aa.name, sum(aml.debit) as debit, sum(aml.credit) as credit "
                         "from account_move_line as aml "
                         "left join account_account as aa on aml.account_id = aa.id "
                         "where date >= '%s' and date <= '%s' "
                         "group by aa.code, aa.name "
                         "order by aa.code " % (date_start,date_end))
        for r in self.env.cr.fetchall():
            datos.append({
                'code': r[0],
                'name': r[1],
                'debit': r[2],
                'credit': r[3]
            })
            debit_total += r[2]
            credit_total += r[3]
        return {
            'company_id': company_id,
            'company': company_id,
            'currency': company_id.currency_id,
            'date_start': data['form']['date_from_str'],
            'date_end': data['form']['date_to_str'],
            'fecha_actual': datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
            'hora_actual': datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
            'doc': move_line_ids[0],
            'docs': datos,
            'debit_total': debit_total,
            'credit_total': credit_total,
        }
```

I tried with this code

```
def imprimir_xlsx(self):
    
    for rec in self:
        format_new = "%d/%m/%Y"
        data = {
            'ids': 0,
            'form': {
                'date_from': self.date_start,
                'date_to': self.date_end,
                'date_from_str': self.date_start.strftime(format_new),
                'date_to_str': self.date_end.strftime(format_new),
                'company': self.company_id.id
            }
        }


        # Crear el archivo
        output = BytesIO()
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'in_memory': True})
        sheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Reporte')

    # Escribir los encabezados
        sheet.write(0, 0, 'Código')
        sheet.write(0, 1, 'Nombre')
        sheet.write(0, 2, 'Débito')
        sheet.write(0, 3, 'Crédito')

    # Escribir los datos
        row = 1
        for doc in data['docs']:
            sheet.write(row, 0, doc['code'])
            sheet.write(row, 1, doc['name'])
            sheet.write(row, 2, doc['debit'])
            sheet.write(row, 3, doc['credit'])
            row += 1

    # Escribir los totales
        sheet.write(row, 1, 'Total')
        sheet.write(row, 2, data['debit_total'])
        sheet.write(row, 3, data['credit_total'])

    # Cerrar el archivo
        workbook.close()
        output.seek(0)

        return self.env.ref('l10n_ve_full.report_daily_book').report_action(self, data=data)

    # Devolver el archivo como una respuesta HTTP
        return {
            'name': 'report_daily_book.xlsx',
            'type': 'binary',
            'data': output.read(),
            'context': self.env.context,
        }
```

Comment: When I press the print button, it sends me to the page where I download the pdf file, I keep trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [report_xlsx](https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine/tree/15.0/report_xlsx) module. You will need to pass the result of the query defined inside the qweb report parser to the XLSX report.

***Example:***

- Define a report action

  ```
  <record id="report_daily_book_xlsx" model="ir.actions.report">
      <field name="name">Print to XLSX</field>
      <field name="model">account.daily.book</field>
      <field name="report_type">xlsx</field>
      <field name="report_name">report_daily_book</field>
      <field name="report_file">report_daily_book</field>
  </record>
  ```
- Add a report parser (the `update_datas` function is used as an example so you can test this report parser)

  ```
  class ReportDailyBook(models.AbstractModel):
      _name = "report.report_daily_book"
      _inherit = "report.report_xlsx.abstract"
      _description = "Daily Books XLSX Report"

      def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, books):

          self.update_datas(data)

          sheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Reporte")
          # Escribir los encabezados
          sheet.write(0, 0, 'Código')
          sheet.write(0, 1, 'Nombre')
          sheet.write(0, 2, 'Débito')
          sheet.write(0, 3, 'Crédito')

          # Escribir los datos
          row = 1
          for doc in data['docs']:
              sheet.write(row, 0, doc['code'])
              sheet.write(row, 1, doc['name'])
              sheet.write(row, 2, doc['debit'])
              sheet.write(row, 3, doc['credit'])
              row += 1

          # Escribir los totales
          sheet.write(row, 1, 'Total')
          sheet.write(row, 2, data['debit_total'])
          sheet.write(row, 3, data['credit_total'])

      def update_datas(self, data):
          date_start = datetime.strptime(data['form']['date_from'], DATE_FORMAT)
          date_end = datetime.strptime(data['form']['date_to'], DATE_FORMAT)
          company_id = self.env['res.company'].search([('id', '=', data['form']['company'])])
          move_line_ids = self.env['account.move.line'].search([])
          datos = []
          debit_total = 0
          credit_total = 0
          self._cr.execute("select aa.code, aa.name, sum(aml.debit) as debit, sum(aml.credit) as credit "
                           "from account_move_line as aml "
                           "left join account_account as aa on aml.account_id = aa.id "
                           "where date >= '%s' and date <= '%s' "
                           "group by aa.code, aa.name "
                           "order by aa.code " % (date_start, date_end))
          for r in self.env.cr.fetchall():
              datos.append({
                  'code': r[0],
                  'name': r[1],
                  'debit': r[2],
                  'credit': r[3]
              })
              debit_total += r[2]
              credit_total += r[3]

          data['docs'] = datos
          data['debit_total'] = debit_total
          data['credit_total'] = credit_total
  ```
- Return the report action with predefined data in the `imprimir_xlsx` function

  ```
  class AccountDailyBook(models.TransientModel):
      _name = "account.daily.book"

      date_start = fields.Date("Fecha desde", required=True, default=date.today().replace(day=1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
      date_end = fields.Date("Fecha hasta", required=True, default=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
      company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', required=True, default=lambda self: self.env.company)

      def imprimir_xlsx(self):
          self.ensure_one()
          format_new = "%d/%m/%Y"
          data = {
              'ids': 0,
              'form': {
                  'date_from': self.date_start,
                  'date_to': self.date_end,
                  'date_from_str': self.date_start.strftime(format_new),
                  'date_to_str': self.date_end.strftime(format_new),
                  'company': self.company_id.id
              }
          }
          return self.env.ref('l10n_ve_full.report_daily_book_xlsx').report_action(self, data=data)
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but it still exports the data in PDF and not in XlSX

Comment: Did you install `report_xlsx` module and added a button to call ``imprimir_xlsx`` function?

Comment: yes, i installed report_xlsx and a added the button imprimir_xlsx

Comment: but it still keeps printing me in pdf.. i need in xlsx :/

Comment: I tested it and it works. Please update your question to include the new changes

Comment: I deleted the code and put the same as yours and I get the following error-->

Mensaje de error:

Error when render the template
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__
Template: 2183
Path: /t/t/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span
Node: <span t-esc="'{0:,.2f}'.format(credit_total)"/>
El error ocurrió durante la creación de la plantilla 2183 y evalua la siguiente expresión: <span t-esc="'{0:,.2f}'.format(credit_total)"/>

Comment: This is a qweb error which mean `credit_total` is `None`.

Comment: How can I fix it, the value leaves it at 0 or even change to none and it keeps giving me the error

Comment: The report parser should include the `credit_total` to the context, make sure to use the report name in the report parser `_name` attribute (`'report.module.report_name'`).

Comment: it still shows the data in pdf and does not export it directly in excel

Comment: Updated the report action to use a different ID, In my previous example, it will use the qweb report action.  It worked for me because I do not have a qweb report. I will write a demo module if you need it

Comment: yes, please i need it

Comment: try the following code -> row += 1
        if not isinstance(data['debit_total'], (int, float)):
            data['debit_total'] = 0.0
        sheet.write(row, 1, 'Total')
        sheet.write(row, 2, '{0:,.2f}'.format(data['debit_total']))
        sheet.write(row, 2, '{0:,.2f}'.format(data['credit_total']))

but it still throws me the qweb error
Error when render the template
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__
Template: 2183
Path: /t/t/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/span
Node: <span t-esc="'{0:,.2f}'.format(debit_total)"/>

Comment: I comment the line of code of that xml and it keeps showing me the same thing, it is as if the modifications were not updated